# Converting API call to pandas dataframe(or csv) - ValueError: Protocol not known

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

First time doing an API call. From my understanding the flow is like this:
API call --> Convert API call to json dict --> convert dict to str --> use pandas function to get df

I've googled the above error but can't find a solution.

```
response = requests.get('https://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/MEI/AUS+AUT+BEL+CAN+CHL+COL+CZE+DNK+EST+FIN+FRA+DEU+GRC+HUN+ISL+IRL+ISR+ITA+JPN+KOR+LVA+LTU+LUX+MEX+NLD+NZL+NOR+POL+PRT+SVK+SVN+ESP+SWE+CHE+TUR+GBR+USA+EA19+EU28+G4E+G-7+NAFTA+OECDE+G-20+OECD+SDR+ONM+A5M+NMEC+ARG+BRA+BGR+CHN+CRI+CYP+IND+IDN+MLT+ROU+RUS+SAU+ZAF.LO+LORS+LORSGP+LORSGPRT+LORSGPNO+LORSGPTD+LORSGPOR+LOLI+LOLITO+LOLITOAA+LOLITONO+LOLITOTR+LOCO+LOCOPA+LOCOPANO+LOCOPAOR+LOCOAB+LOCOABNO+LOCOABOR+LOCOBS+LOCOBSNO+LOCOBSOR+LOCOBU+LOCOBUNO+LOCOBUOR+LOCOBD+LOCOBDNO+LOCOBDOR+LOCOBE+LOCOBENO+LOCOBEOR+LOCOBX+LOCOBXNO+LOCOBXOR+LOCOBF+LOCOBFNO+LOCOBFOR+LOCOBO+LOCOBONO+LOCOBOOR+LOCOBI+LOCOBINO+LOCOBIOR+LOCOBP+LOCOBPNO+LOCOBPOR+LOCOBC+LOCOBCNO+LOCOBCOR+LOCOBK+LOCOBKNO+LOCOBKOR+LOCOVR+LOCOVRNO+LOCOVROR+LOCODW+LOCODWNO+LOCODWOR+LOCOPC+LOCOPCNO+LOCOPCOR+LOCOCI+LOCOCINO+LOCOCIOR+LOCOCE+LOCOCENO+LOCOCEOR+LOCOEX+LOCOEXNO+LOCOEXOR+LOCOEM+LOCOEMNO+LOCOEMOR+LOCOTX+LOCOTXNO+LOCOTXOR+LOCOXG+LOCOXGNO+LOCOXGOR+LOCOHS+LOCOHSNO+LOCOHSOR+LOCOTM+LOCOTMNO+LOCOTMOR+LOCOMG+LOCOMGNO+LOCOMGOR+LOCOIS+LOCOISNO+LOCOISOR+LOCOLT+LOCOLTNO+LOCOLTOR+LOCOMA+LOCOMANO+LOCOMAOR+LOCONT+LOCONTNO+LOCONTOR+LOCOOD+LOCOODNO+LOCOODOR+LOCOPP+LOCOPPNO+LOCOPPOR+LOCOPB+LOCOPBNO+LOCOPBOR+LOCOPE+LOCOPENO+LOCOPEOR+LOCOPG+LOCOPGNO+LOCOPGOR+LOCOPQ+LOCOPQNO+LOCOPQOR+LOCOPM+LOCOPMNO+LOCOSL+LOCOSLNO+LOCOSLOR+LOCOSP+LOCOSPNO+LOCOSPOR+LOCOST+LOCOSTNO+LOCOSTOR+LOCOSI+LOCOSINO+LOCOSIOR+LOCOSK+LOCOSKNO+LOCOSKOR+LOCOTT+LOCOTTNO+LOCOTTOR+LOCOTA+LOCOTANO+LOCOTAOR.ST+STSA+IXOB+IXOBSA+GY+GYSA.Q+M/all?startTime=2019-Q1&endTime=2020-Q4&pid=c143790b-58dd-42b7-b4b5-7c19c50c9d63')

# Convert API call to dict
data = json.loads(response.text)
# Convert dict to str
data_string = json.dumps(data)

df = pd.read_json(data_string) 




ValueError: Protocol not known: {"header": {"id": "810a5935-d894-4ff9-a1f3-e39d6712a616", "test": false, "prepared": "2020-11-14T15:06:31.0326305Z", "sender": {"id": "OECD", "name": "Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development"}, "links": [{"href": "https
```

Comment: You can't just pass any data and expect pandas to make sense of the data structure. See the output of response.json() and select the elements where your data is.

Comment: How do I select an element? For example here https://imgur.com/gallery/7YD4vMv
I have the country element which I would like in my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to learn the structure of the data. The api *should* be documented so you can figure out what you want to pull out of it.
Here's how I go about it:
Once you create the data object, look at the keys.

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
In [49]: data.keys()
Out[49]: dict_keys(['header', 'dataSets', 'structure'])
```

Then look at each key

```
data['header'] # don't think you want this
data['dataSets'] # this is what you want? but is a list
data['structure'] # complex structure
```

if you get errors reading into pandas dataframe, look at the type; this is a list
so take the first element [0]

```
In [59]: type(data['dataSets'])
Out[59]: list
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data['dataSets'][0]))
```

Even this complex structure

```
In [57]: pd.read_json(json.dumps(data['dataSets'][0]))
    ...:
Out[57]:
               action                                             series
0:0:0:0   Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
0:14:0:0  Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
0:15:0:0  Information  {'attributes': [0, 2, 0, None], 'observations'...
0:1:0:0   Information  {'attributes': [0, 1, 1, None], 'observations'...
0:24:0:0  Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
...               ...                                                ...
9:85:0:0  Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
9:86:0:0  Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
9:8:0:0   Information  {'attributes': [0, 0, 0, None], 'observations'...
9:9:0:0   Information  {'attributes': [0, 2, 0, None], 'observations'...
9:9:1:0   Information  {'attributes': [0, 2, 0, None], 'observations'...
```

You'll need to figure out what it is you really want from this data set. Because it's complex you may find yourself transforming the data or doing complex mapping to get it into a workable state.